# Entity Framework compilation error in return methods

Tags: c#

I imported a database to my visual studio project. Here is the code from my main.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EntityFramework
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();

            foreach (var customer in db.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.ContactName);
            }
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(string,
>   params System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some
>   invalid arguments

When I double click on it I automatically go to this method:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<CustOrderHist_Result> CustOrderHist(string customerID)
{
    var customerIDParameter = customerID != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", customerID) :
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(string));

//The error shows that the problem is in the return
                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CustOrderHist_Result>("CustOrderHist", customerIDParameter);
            }
```

It shows that the problem is in the return of the method. This error occurs everywhere where return like this is written. I haven't written these functions. Entity framework has created them automatically. Do you have any suggestions where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to investigate :

- Are you sure that your customerID in DB is in string format ? Is it
  not a incremental int ?
- Are you using SQL Server or another DB ?

The autogenerated file.Designer.cs is ever good for simple stored procedure as retrieve a not complex object, so I think your SP is not correctly imported in edmx. Check if SP method is correct type for I/O, check too if you are using another DB as SQL Server to configure the good OleDB.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the reference

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

and add

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

in your context class.